# How can i check if the input from a textbox == "{" or "}"?

Tags: c#

I am trying to check if the user wrote { or } into a textbox.

Here is the if statement:

```
private void btn_convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_output.Text = "";
    try
    {
        if (txb_code.Text.Substring(0, 1) == "{" || txb_code.Text.Substring(0, 1) == "}")
        {
            lbl_output.Text = "In Python gibt es kein { oder }.\nStattdessen muss der darauffolgende\n Code um einen Tab (4 Leerzeichen)\neingeschoben werden.\n Beispiel in Python:\nif(i == 1):\n\tprint(\"i ist 1!\")";
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Before trying to get a substring from the TextBox, better check first whether the textbox contains actually any text and is not empty. Aside from that, what problem do you have?

Comment: This if statement is only triggered when a button is pressed.

Comment: It doesn't recognise the "{" and the "}".

Comment: Of course it does, if the `{` or `}` is the very first character in the textbox. Look at how you use Substring. Read the documentation for `String.Substring` to learn what the code you have written there actually does...

Comment: So what do i have to change with Substring?

Comment: I am new on Stackoverflow so it would be really nice if you could give me more clear answers.

Comment: Do you want to know if the TextBox contains one of those brackets **ANYWHERE** in it?...or just at the beginning, or just at the end?...do you care which bracket is at the beginning and/or end? etc...

Comment: Just if the first letter is a bracket.

Comment: Then the [string.StartsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8) would fit and express better what you're trying to do there. And here's how you use it: `txb_code.Text.StartsWith("{")`

Comment: An **EMPTY** catch block is always a bad sign.  Put some kind of MessageBox or Console.WriteLine() in there so you know if an exception is occurring and you're not seeing it otherwise.

Comment: Should i post the full code?

Comment: I'd start with outputting something in that catch block(s).  Test it and see what happens.

Comment: What was the issue with your code?...

Comment: It was a weird issue with the Substring and {. But now everything helps. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just if the first letter is a bracket.

Then I'd use [StartsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_StartsWith_System_String_) like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txb_code.Text.StartsWith("{"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bracket in first position present.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bracket in first position NOT present.");
    }
}
```

If you really want either kind of bracket at the beginning, then:

```
if (txb_code.Text.StartsWith("{") || txb_code.Text.StartsWith("}"))
```

Comment: Hmm thats weird. I am still getting no output.

Comment: Where are you looking for output?

Comment: Label. Code for output is: `lbl_output.Text = "test";`

Comment: Well...you're making a mistake somewhere.  We can't help you fix it with just the code you've shown us.  We're gonna need more to go off of...

Comment: I hope this actually helped you solve your problem.